# I am trying to define a Linked list in Python, but why it is always going to add first element

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.key = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

L1 = LinkedList()
print(L1.head)

def Insert(key,root):
    temp = root
    if (root != None):
        while(temp.next):
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = Node(key)
        print("donr next")

    else:
        root = Node(key)
        print("doneroot")

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    Insert(list1[i],L1.head)

def printing(ll):
    temp = ll.head
    print("printing")
    print(temp)
    while(temp):
        print(temp.key)
        temp = temp.next

printing(L1)
```

The ouput is:

> None
>   doneroot
>   doneroot
>   doneroot
>   doneroot
>   doneroot
>   printing
>   None

Why it is always adding to the root element

Comment: The problem is that you are never actually setting the `head` of the `LinkedList`. The problem is with passing the **value of an object**, but not the **refference to an object**. I'll post details shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, everything is passed by reference. When the passed object is immutable, the label actually gets reassigned in its scope. For example:

```
def modify_a_list(x):  # lists are mutable
    x.append(1)

def modify_a_string(x):  # strings are immutable
    x += 'bar'

a = [3,2]
modify_a_list(a)
print(a)  # gives [3, 2, 1]

b = 'text'
modify_a_string(b)
print(b)  # prints 'text' and not 'textbar'.
```

In your example, when you pass `L1.head` as a parameter, it resolves to `None` and the newly defined `label | variable` named `root` inside you method reassigns to a new `Node`. But you wanted to assign it to attribute `head` of the linked list. This can be solved by passing the linked list as the parameter.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.key = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

L1 = LinkedList()
print(L1.head)

def Insert(key, ll):
    temp = ll.head
    if ll.head is not None:
        while temp.next:
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = Node(key)
        print("donr next")

    else:
        ll.head = Node(key)
        print("doneroot")

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    Insert(list1[i], L1)

def printing(ll):
    temp = ll.head
    print("printing")
    print(temp)
    while temp:
        print(temp.key)
        temp = temp.next

printing(L1)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the concept and the error which I made?